# How to create BTC to USD calculator with vice versa conversion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

In the attached code, I have `BTC` to `USD` conversions working correctly, However, I am struggling to introduce a bilateral conversion from `USD` to `BTC`.

How can I have these two conversions working in parallel?

Thank you in advance for your efforts.

```js
$("input[name='calc']").keyup(function(){
 $.getJSON( "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/usd.json", 
    function( data) {
    var amountInBtc = parseFloat($("input[name='calc']").val());
    //convert btc to usd
    var exchangeRate = parseInt(data.bpi.USD.rate_float);
    var amount = amountInBtc * exchangeRate;
    $("input[name='rslt']").val(amount);
    });
});
```

```css
.calculator{
  display:flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>




<!--------- Calculator----------------->
    <div class="calculator">
      <input type="number" name="calc" placeholder="BTC">
      <div class="arrow" style="margin: 0 10px";>=</div>
      <input type="number" name="rslt" placeholder="USD">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below... simple approach is to use a class for both fields and call the onChange function on the class, and use variables for the field names instead of hard coding them inside your function. Also note that using toFixed(2) fixes 2 decimal points, which will be 0.00 for anything less than 0.01.
Everything else is self explanatory

```js
$(".currencyField").keyup(function(){ //input[name='calc']
 let convFrom;
 if($(this).prop("name") == "btc") {
       convFrom = "btc";
       convTo = "usd";
 }
 else {
       convFrom = "usd";
       convTo = "btc";
 }
 $.getJSON( "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/usd.json", 
    function( data) {
    var origAmount = parseFloat($("input[name='" + convFrom + "']").val());        
    var exchangeRate = parseInt(data.bpi.USD.rate_float);
    let amount;
    if(convFrom == "btc")
       amount = parseFloat(origAmount * exchangeRate);
    else
       amount = parseFloat(origAmount/ exchangeRate); 
    $("input[name='" + convTo + "']").val(amount.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

```css
.calculator{
  display:flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>




<!--------- Calculator----------------->
    <div class="calculator">
      <input type="number" name="btc" class="currencyField" placeholder="BTC">
      <div class="arrow" style="margin: 0 10px";>=</div>
      <input type="number" name="usd" class="currencyField" placeholder="USD">
    </div>
```

Comment: You can pick any number inside toFixed. Also change it based on the value entered. And do you mind marking it as accepted answer?

Comment: Good! it works fine and this what I want. but there's one problem! `.toFixed(2);` doesn't work when converting small USD amount. ex: 1 usd = 0.00 btc. so I changed it to `.toFixed(8);` and it worked. but it also effect the USD `input`like this 0.00000000. can I solve this also? God bless you bro and thanks so much for assisting me.